Gen 7:4 "for in seven days" - is that current_time + 7 days or inclusive counting ie 'on the seventh day'

For in seven days I will send rain on the earth forty days and forty nights, and every living thing that I have made I will blot out from the face of the ground.”

Does this mean the flood started:

+7 days after God made this statement or
is this inclusive counting ie Day 1 is when God made the statement and +6 days = Day 7 when the rains started.


It is true that the Bible frequently uses inclusive reckoning when stating time periods.  However, the evidence in Gen 7:4 is against this because of the grammatical construction.  Here is my literal translation:

For after days seven more, I will rain on the earth ...

Note the use of the adverb "more" עוד ('od) highlighted above.  If this had been "one day more" it would be the next day.  Thus, "seven days more" means one week from now.

NKJV, NASB20, LSB, and others all agree with "seven more days".
